# Getting the right resolution of cv::VideoCaputre in opencv?=

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I have a camera with a resolution of : 1280x1024  when I start my program I got a frame with 680x420,  but  I can't work with this. so here what I did

```
cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1280);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,1024);
```

the Problem that I have is that my program should work with different cameras, how can I make sure that opencv is getting the correct resolution alone?

Comment: If setting the capture properties doesn't always work, you could `cv::resize()` to your desired resolution before anything else. You might run into some aspect-ratio issues, but you would at least have a consistent image resolution.

Answer (score 0):

680 x 420 is a "correct" resolution as far as openCV is concerned. If you want an image with a specific resolution, you will need to tell opencv what resolution to use (as you are doing now).

If openCV can not use the provided resolution, it will use the nearest possible values.